# Is event not passed on bootstrap-react component's onChange prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

In one of my classes, I have this function that handles changes of a React-bootstrap radio button group:

```
handleChange(value){
  this.setState({ value: value })
}
```

This works but I don't understand why. The value is passed directly instead of event. In my understanding, functions that handle events should accept *event* as parameter and to access the value of the element that called the function I should use: `event.state.value`

But when I pass event and use `event.state.value`, I'm getting an error saying:

> Cannot read value of undefined

This is my render function:

```
  render(){
    return(
      <React.Fragment>
        <ToggleButtonGroup type="radio" name="options" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          <ToggleButton value={1} variant="outline-dark">Option 1</ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton value={2} variant="outline-dark">Option 2</ToggleButton>
          <ToggleButton value={3} variant="outline-dark">Option 3</ToggleButton>
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
```

Can someone explain why my code behaves like that?

By the way I installed react and react-bootstrap using CDN not `npm`.

Comment: In React Bootstrap, the `ToggleButtonGroup` passes the value directly to the change handler. See docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-group-props).

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you put that as an answer so I can accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React Bootstrap, the `ToggleButtonGroup` passes the value directly to the change handler. See docs [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/buttons/#toggle-button-group-props).